# Retrieve from sql data, adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm trying to retrieve data from a list I was able to create using `SqlConnection`.

I understand how to repopulate my text boxes by selecting an item from the list box (component).  But how would I get data by using a separate button, or timeline event, and fill out the text boxes. t_fname t_lname t_phone

```
var connection:SQLConnection;

openDatabase();
t_phone.restrict = "0-9";

function openDatabase():void
{
var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("database.db");
connection = new SQLConnection();
connection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, onOpen);
connection.openAsync(dbFile, SQLMode.CREATE);
}

function onOpen(SQLEvent):void
{
var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
stat.sqlConnection = connection;
stat.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, phone INTEGER)";
stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems));
}

function selectItems(SQLEvent):void
    {
    b_save.enabled = false;
    b_delete.enabled = false;
    var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stat.sqlConnection = connection;
    stat.text = "SELECT id, fname, lname, phone FROM contacts ORDER BY id";
    stat.execute(-1, new Responder(onSelected));
    }

function onSelected(evt:SQLResult):void
{
if (evt.data != null)
{
itemList.dataProvider = new DataProvider();
for (var i:int=0; i<evt.data.length; i++)
{
itemList.addItem({label:(evt.data[i].fname + " " + evt.data[i].lname), data:evt.data[i]});
}
}
}

b_new.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, createNew);

function createNew(MouseEvent):void
{
var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
stat.sqlConnection = connection;
stat.text = "INSERT INTO contacts (fname, lname, phone) VALUES (@fname, @lname, @phone)";
stat.parameters["@fname"] = t_fname.text;
stat.parameters["@lname"] = t_lname.text;
stat.parameters["@phone"] = t_phone.text;
stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems));
t_fname.text = t_lname.text = t_phone.text = "";
}

itemList.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);

function onChange(evt:Event):void
{
b_save.enabled = true;
b_delete.enabled = true;
t_fname.text = evt.target.selectedItem.data.fname;
t_lname.text = evt.target.selectedItem.data.lname;
t_phone.text = evt.target.selectedItem.data.phone;

}

b_save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveThis);

function saveThis(MouseEvent):void
{
var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
stat.sqlConnection = connection;
stat.text = "UPDATE contacts SET fname=@fname, lname=@lname, phone=@phone WHERE id=" + itemList.selectedItem.data.id;
stat.parameters["@fname"] = t_fname.text;
stat.parameters["@lname"] = t_lname.text;
stat.parameters["@phone"] = t_phone.text;
stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems));
t_fname.text = t_lname.text = t_phone.text = "";
}

b_delete.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteThis);

function deleteThis(MouseEvent):void
{
var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
stat.sqlConnection = connection;
stat.text = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id=" + itemList.selectedItem.data.id;
stat.execute(-1, new Responder(selectItems));
t_fname.text = t_lname.text = t_phone.text = "";
}

////     ?how would I do it for this recall button ?

b_recall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, recall1);

function recall1(MouseEvent):void
{

t_fname.text =  data from the first entry
t_lname.text = data from the first entry
t_phone.text = data from the first entry
}
```

Comment: You can store it in an object.  oEntry = new Object(); oEntry.t_fname = "whatever";  You can push objects into array if you need.  aEntries = new Array(); aEntries.push(oEntry);  trace("first name: " + aEntries[0].t_fname);

Comment: Thanks, I don't have enough programming skill to implement this . why can't I just extract what is already in my table - I suppose my question is - How do i identify the data and display it from another button.... just as `t_fname.text = evt.target.selectedItem.data.fname;` is able to extract and display on list.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used components.  If itemList is the name of your component, try itemList.selectedItem.data.fname to reference the selected fname.  You can get help by asking question about component specifically.

Comment: thanks. that worked if I want to get the data from the selected item on the list.  But I'm trying to get data from specific id.  For example - I have 4 rows, id 7,8,9,10 . How do I get fname from id8 . ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the data.  It's harder to learn to work around not storing the data.  Here's  the basic code to add to your code. First line is your existing code, add new below it.

```
t_phone.restrict = "0-9";
var aItems:Array;
var oItem:Object;
var i:uint;
```

The first line is another line of your code, add the code below it - sorry that wasn't clear:

```
itemList.addItem({label:(evt.data[i].fname + " " + evt.data[i].lname), data:evt.data[i]});
//  add item to end of aItems array
oItem = new Object();
oItem.t_id = evt.data[i].itemID;
oItem.t_fname = evt.data[i].fname;
oItem.t_fname = evt.data[i].lname;
oItem.t_phone = evt.data[i].phone;
aItems.push(oItem);
```

Then you can loop through your array and look for matching id or whatever.

```
//  loop through aItems to find match for t_id
for (var i:int = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
    if(aItems[i].t_id == testID){
        trace("f_name: " + aItems[i].t_fname);
    }
}
```